# Date just a number after lapply

Tags: r, plot, lapply

I have a vector of dates that are to be changed. But after lapply the dates take up double behaviour.

```
DF<- data.frame(col1=c(1, 2, 3), time=strptime(c("12:01", "12:02", "12:03"), format="%H:%M"))
t<-DF$time
t<-lapply(t, function(x){if (x> strptime("12:02",format="%H:%M") ){x - (24*3600)}else{x}})
DF$time<-t
DF
#  col1    time
#1    1 1.4e+09
#2    2 1.4e+09
#3    3 1.4e+09
```

If I look at DF$time I get

```
DF$time
#[[1]]
#[1] "2015-11-09 12:01:00 CET"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "2015-11-09 12:02:00 CET"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "2015-11-08 12:03:00 CET"
```

But especially for plotting, the dates are just numbers. (`with(DF, plot(col1,time, type="b"))`)

[image]

Comment: What is the question?  What do you want?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I think they want the column to retain its class. With their code, it goes from some flavor of datetime to `list`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**base R** As Roland suggested, this can be done in base with

```
# op's example data
DF <- data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3), time=strptime(c("12:01","12:02","12:03"),format="%H:%M"))

# one-liner:
DF$time[DF$time > strptime("12:02",format="%H:%M")] <- 
DF$time[DF$time > strptime("12:02",format="%H:%M")] - 24*3600

# or, a longer option:
DF$time <- replace(
  DF$time, 
  DF$time > strptime("12:02",format="%H:%M"), 
  DF$time[DF$time > strptime("12:02",format="%H:%M")] - 24*3600
)
```

The `class` of the column (POSIXct) is preserved when we modify part of a vector like this.

```
# 'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ col1: num  1 2 3
#  $ time: POSIXct, format: "2015-11-09 12:01:00" "2015-11-09 12:02:00" "2015-11-08 12:03:00"
```

With `lapply` and related functions, preserving `class` is hard:

```
Lres  <- lapply(DF$time, function(x) if (x > strptime("12:02",format="%H:%M")  ) x - (24*3600) else x)
class(Lres)  # list 

uLres <- unlist(Lres)
class(uLres) # numeric 

Sres  <- sapply(DF$time, function(x) if (x > strptime("12:02",format="%H:%M")  ) x - (24*3600) else x)
class(Sres)  # numeric
```

This behavior is documented in the "Value" section of `help("lapply")`: `lapply` gives a list and `sapply` gives a vector with one of the atomic classes (which does not include POSIXct) if it can.

---

**data.table** I would use data.table, which has nice syntax for changing part of a vector:

```
library(data.table)
DF <- data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3), time=strptime(c("12:01","12:02","12:03"),format="%H:%M"))

setDT(DF)[ time > strptime("12:02",format="%H:%M"), time := time - 24*3600 ]
```

---

**data.table integer formats** The package has separate date and time formats as well:

```
DF <- data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3), time=strptime(c("12:01","12:02","12:03"),format="%H:%M"))

setDT(DF)
DF[, c("d","t") := .(as.IDate(time), as.ITime(time))]
DF[, time := NULL] # remove original column

DF[ t > as.ITime("12:02"), d := d-1L ]

#    col1          d        t
# 1:    1 2015-11-09 12:01:00
# 2:    2 2015-11-09 12:02:00
# 3:    3 2015-11-08 12:03:00
```

These are integer-based, so you won't be able to store fractional seconds in `t`.

Comment: Or in base R: `DF[DF$time> strptime("12:02",format="%H:%M"), "time"] <- DF[DF$time> strptime("12:02",format="%H:%M"), "time"] - 24 * 3600`.

Comment: Thanks @Roland -- added

Comment: Maybe you should add that `lapply` returns a list and there is no convenient way to transform that list to a vector without loosing the datetime attributes.